# Detecting whether Android input Widget changes were made by the user and not by the framework

Tags: android

I have a form consisting of some `EditText`, `Spinner` and `DatePicker` widgets.

I have a Confirm and a Save button. I want the Save button to be initially hidden. When the user modifies one of the form items, I want to hide the Confirm button and then show the Save button.

I tried:

- `setOnClickListener()`. The listener is not called. I believe the widgets trap it to implement the higher-level functions.
- The widget-specific listeners like `TextWatcher` and `OnItemSelectedListener`. But they are called when the widget as part of the widget initialization. I would like to know if they are called by user activity.

My target is Android 3.2/SDK 13.